# Authorize Not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication, authorize-attribute

Hi after exhausting pretty much every tutorial found on the internet, i still wasnt able to fix my problem, it appears that despite the authorize tag on my controller, it still allows every request even if they are not logged in.

WebConfig

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login"  timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Home Controller

```
 [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

        return View();
    }
```

Login

```
  public ActionResult Login()
    {
        InitializeDropdown();
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        //selects model state errors if any
        var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //AccountService accountService = new AccountService();

            bool loginsuccess = AccountService.login(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Domain);

            if (loginsuccess == false)
            {

                ModelState.AddModelError("", Session["Error"].ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false);
                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                    && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                //FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(model.UserName, false);
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

RegisterGlobalFilters

```
  public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
    }
```

GLOBAL ASAX

```
   public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        //WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        //AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();


    }


    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
    }
```

Did i miss anything?

Answer (score 0):

No, your code seems right. Even the Authorize attribute over the home controller is redundant, because you already registered it globally for all controllers in RegisterGlobalFilters method.

Does the AccountService.login method work? Maybe it returns always true.

Comment: hi i have this menu bar on top of my page, what im doing is that im clicking the home link already, it will then fire the home controller.. to my amazement my get metho will push even without logging

Comment: @anonymous1110 it is strange because if you try to create a new application from scratch, then it will work (it redirects you to login page). My advice is to create a new mvc project - compare the web configs, look at the global.asax.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the session cookie is created:

[image]

Also  try to return the username you used to log in. Use the code below or just simply view this value using debugger.

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Test()
{
    return Content(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
}
```

Comment: my user identity.name uses my windows nt login. This should not be the case right? since it should use the form authentication. How can i fix this?

Comment: Not the case as you use <authentication mode="Forms">. 
So when you called this Test action, you got your username, which means you are logged in. Now try to logout with FormsAuthentication.SignOut(); and try to call Test action again.

Comment: when i tried logging in, it now shows my form login username. I noticed that when im not logged in via login page my user.identity.name appears to be my windows nt login. is this correct?

Comment: also even if i logged out using FormsAuthentication.SignOut(); my user identity name is also my windows login.. @_@

Comment: i guess my problem here is that when im not logged in my user.identity.name uses my windows nt login, if im logged in via log in page, my identity.name changes to my form login. weird

Comment: That's not normal. Your application behaves as if you had <authentication mode="Windows"> in your web.config. Check it again. Make sure <authentication mode="forms"> is placed within <system.web> section.

Comment: I have just confirmed it. If <authentication mode="forms"> is missing or you application can read it for some reason you User.Identity will be current Windows user.

Comment: i already have it inside the system web tag  <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login"  timeout="2880" />
</authentication> but to no avail

Answer (score 0):

Check if the Global.asax.cs is missing these types:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
```